# Facebook post sharing notification

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been searching for a while to determine a way to receive a notification when someone shares a post that I posted on my company facebook page. Ideally, I would like to see the person's name or email address so that I can enter them in a competition.

does anyone know if this is possible?

thanks so much

Comment: "You must not condition registration or entry upon the user taking any action using any Facebook features or functionality other than liking a Page, checking in to a Place, or connecting to your app. For example, you must not condition registration or entry upon the user liking a Wall post, or commenting or uploading a photo on a Wall." from https://www.facebook.com/page_guidelines.php. Just saying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm affraid there's no way to do this, if they do the share under facebook.com. If they are doing it on your domain you can use the Javascript sdk's [Events](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) to catch when a user clicks on a like, however you still won't get an email with just that.

#### But

Even if you could get these informations, facebook doesn't allow you to use their channels as an entry mechanism for your promotion, check the [promotion guidelines](http://www.facebook.com/page_guidelines.php#promotionsguidelines) and see the introduction videos the [guidelines](http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10100938382101566) and on [platform plolicies](http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10100938363379086).